# How to lemmatize with stanford-nlp tools?

Tags: php, nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I have installed the PHP API to the NLP Stanford tools (from https://github.com/agentile/PHP-Stanford-NLP) and I have managed to obtain POS tagging using the code example included there:

```
$pos = new \StanfordNLP\POSTagger(
  '/path/to/stanford-postagger-2014-08-27/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger',
  '/path/to/stanford-postagger-2014-08-27/stanford-postagger.jar'
);
$result = $pos->tag(explode(' ', "What does the fox say?"));
var_dump($result);
```

However, I also need lemmas. My question is: Is it possible to get them with the POS tagger? Or should I use the [CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) for that?

If the latter is the case, how do I run it in PHP?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow, that shocked me. A whole question where I understood _not one word, and definitely none of the acronyms_ except PHP

Comment: If you want to help, you can tell me what part is not clear and I can try to clarify, but if you're not a NLP or Standord-NLP user you might not be able to help.

Comment: I would love to be able to help, but like I said, I have been reminded that I for one definitely do not know it all, _Not that I really needed reminding of that_

Answer (score 0):

- I think you do need CoreNLP. As far as I know, only CoreNLP has the lemmatizer class.
- There are PHP packages. In your CoreNLP link, check "Additional Tools => Extensions => Other programming languages"

  - If you want to use CoreNLP, use the CoreNLP server, which is Java based, so you need to install a Java environment together with PHP
  - After installing CoreNLP server you can make calls to it over the command line. The PHP packages can do that for you